# Silverlight: GridSplitter inside ScrollViewer behaving unexpectedly

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer, gridsplitter

I'm trying to build a two-column layout where the width of the columns can be changed by using a splitter. The right column's width shouldn't change when the browser window is resized (it shouldn't be proportional to the grid width). Both columns should have a minimum width. When the browser window is too narrow to display both columns a scrollbar should appear.

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" MinWidth="400" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="300*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" x:Name="LeftColumn"></Grid>
            <sdk:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Background="Black" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Green" x:Name="RightColumn"></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The problem I'm having is when the splitter is dragged to the left and the left column's minwidth is reached - the right column begins to grow very rapidly and the scrollbar appears. Removing the width setting from the right column eliminates the weird behavior but now the right column starts to grow proportionally when the window is resized...

I'd like the splitter to behave the same way as when it is dragged to the right - I'd like it to stop after the minwidth is reached.

Comment: Curious behavior... however when set the third column's width to 100* it stopped growing. By the way, ¿why did you put the Grid inside the ScrollViewer?

Comment: @NestorArturo - setting the width to 100* makes the third column proportional, which is not the behavior I need. I put a grid inside the scrollviewer so that when the browser window is resized to be narrower than the minimum width of the grid - a horizontal scrollbar is displayed and the UI is still usable.

Comment: @NestorArturo - Defining the column widths with no "*" stops the grid from stretching to the available width of the screen. I'd like the grid to occupy all of the available horizontal real estate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was finally able to come up with a workaround. I'm forcing the width in the code-behind when the layout is changing.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid x:Name="Workspace" Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" MinWidth="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" LayoutUpdated="Workspace_LayoutUpdated">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="300*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" x:Name="LeftColumn"></Grid>
            <sdk:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Background="Black" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Green" x:Name="RightColumn"></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Workspace_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Workspace.Width = Scroller.ViewportWidth - 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the "HorizontalScrollBarVisibility".
This code works for me:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <Grid Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" MinWidth="400" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="300*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red" x:Name="LeftColumn"></Grid>
            <sdk:GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Background="Black" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Green" x:Name="RightColumn"></Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The ScrollViewer gives the grid endless space to grow. Hence the minWidth never stops it.
Obviously there is no need of ScrollViewer that is disabled both vertically and horizontally. Better move the scroll bar inside the grid surrounding the content of every column.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot move the scroll bars inside the content of the column. I need to be able to scroll the whole grid horizontally when the browser window is too narrow to provide an acceptable view. As you have correctly noticed, having a ScrollViewer with completely disabled scroll bars has no purpose.

Comment: What happens here is that the scrollviewer gives infinite space to its immediate children... is it possible to put the ScrollViewer as the LayoutRoot so your Grid will be the immediate child of the outer Grid?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it behaves this way is that you have specified the first column `Width="300*"` with asterisks, 
and the third column `Width="100"` *without* asterisks.

Just put asterisks to the first and third columns, or remove respectively, and it will work the way you wish.

Comment: Verbeia - could you explain why adding the asterisks or star-sizing to both columns does the trick?  I'm bumping into the same problem but my right-hand column isn't always visible until something is selected and at that point I want the right-hand column to get the size of the user control being displayed within it (i.e. column width=auto)  But, if I do this it behaves terribly...